# uwsgi worker keep idle after respawning

Tags: django, uwsgi

#### Environment

- OS: Linux (4.15.0-1043-aws) / Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 64 bit
- Python: 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30)
- uwsgi: 2.0.17.1
- App server: Django 2.1.1
- Web server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

#### Problem

I use `nginx + uwsgi + django` to setup web server, and some times I found the response is so slowly and I have to use the `touch command` which `uwsgi` provided to reload the sever.

After using [`uwsgitop`](https://github.com/xrmx/uwsgitop) to monitor my `uwsgi` server, I found that some `uwsgi workers` keep idle after being respawned, and these workers' `RSS` and `VSZ` are zero, as the following image shows.

[image]

I didn't find any error info in `uwsgi` log, the spawning info is normal like this:

```
worker 6 killed successfully (pid: 14872)
Respawned uWSGI worker 6 (new pid: 5545)

worker 9 killed successfully (pid: 14878)
Respawned uWSGI worker 9 (new pid: 3807)
```

If I use `kill -9 worker-pid` command to respawn the worker, most time the workers can be respawned successful and own `RSS` and `VSZ` and start work, while sometimes just be respawned with zero `RSS` and `VSZ` and keep idle.

I try my best but I can't get a clue what happened to the respawned worker. I post an issue to the [`uwsgi`](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2040) project, but get no response for a long time(It should not be an issue of `uwsgi`).

Any suggestion to debug or inspect this problem?

FYI, This is my `uwsgi` config:

```
# uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# deploy root
deploy_root     = /my/server/path

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = %(deploy_root)/
# Django's wsgi file
module          = MyServer.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = %(deploy_root)/env/

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# socket listen queue size,default 100
listen          = 1024
# respawn processes taking more than 300 seconds
harakiri        = 300
# respawn processes after serving 5000 requests
max-requests    = 5000
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = %(deploy_root)/nginx_uwsgi/server.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 666
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
# run background with log file
daemonize      = %(deploy_root)/nginx_uwsgi/logs/uwsgi.log
# use pid file to stop uwsgi easily
pidfile        = %(deploy_root)/nginx_uwsgi/uwsgi.pid
# use utf8
env            = PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
# use threads
enable-threads = true

# stats socket (use the full path to be safe)
stats          = %(deploy_root)/nginx_uwsgi/stats.sock
# show memory resources uwsgi processes are consuming
memory-report  = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as my comments on `uwsgi issue` [Some worker keep idle after respawning](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2040) shows, this problem caused by third-party module [`APScheduler`](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler).

I use `strace` and `gdb` tools to inspect the idle worker, and find the idle worker just stuck in [`Waiting for the GIL`](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2040#issuecomment-529583621).

So I think this should be caused by threads I created in master process. And the only threads I introduced in master process is `APScheduler background instance` which used to start cron job.

After I move the scheduler jobs logic to a separated process, this problem never happen again.

Comment: How did you do that? Using some other scheduler? Or just used cron? I have similar problem. But instead being idle all workers aren't just respawned after some time. And I also use APScheduler

Comment: Hi @Ralfeus, not really understand your issue. If you mean your workers just are not respawned after some time, you should check your uwsgi config about respawning such as max-requests and so on. Also you can use [uwsgitop](https://github.com/xrmx/uwsgitop) to check your worker's status which maybe give you some clue.